# Jetty7 standalone + jstl/jsp + spring 3 = el/spring tags not working

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl, jetty, el

I'm having some issues with Jetty7 standalone and my spring web app using jsp/jstl/el.
While using maven jetty-plugin everything works fine, but as soon I switch to Jetty standalone, all EL messages eg. `${foobar}` are ignored, as well as spring tags.

My example JSP

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<spring:message var="document_title" code="navigation.activity" />
<spring:message var="header_title" text="" code="navigation.activity" />
hello ${hello}
```

is loaded through spring MVC controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "")
public String test(Model model) throws IOException {
    model.addAttribute("hello", "world");

    return "html/example";
}
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID"
version="2.5">
 ...
```

tried with and without the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>fmt</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>tld</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>c</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>tld</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I even tried to enable EL from within JSP via `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>`, but then I get exceptions like these:

```
An error occurred at line: 21 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/template/html/example.jsp
Generated servlet error:
/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_-any-/jsp/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/template/html/example_jsp.java:268: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method proprietaryEvaluate(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>,javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext,<nulltype>,boolean)
location: class org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl
      out.write((java.lang.String) org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate("${hello}", java.lang.String.class, (PageContext)_jspx_page_context, null, false));
```

I've gone through tons of pages, issues on the web and could not fix this yet.
Hope anyone is able to help me out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what fixed my issue, but I removed all the jsp/jstl dependencies from pom and set web.xml to 3.0.

```
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="Your_Webapp_ID" version="3.0">
```

and all of a sudden it started working.